# Ajax call from jquery works in firefox but not in IE8

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery and I make a ajax call to a webservice that returns some json data. This works perfect in firefox but for some reason not in IE.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://domain.com/Service.svc/data",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        //In firefox this shows the right value of test but in IE8 just "0", why?
        alert(data.d.test);
    }
});
```

I know that the content of the response (data) is:

```
{"d":{"__type":"MyContent:#","test":888.75,"test2":592.5}}
```

So the alert shows 888.75 in firefox but 0 in internet explorer. I can't see why this is happening?

Comment: Run Fiddler and make sure that IE is receiving the correct response.

Comment: By the way, you missed a quote in the URL.

Comment: Would every jquery ajax call from within my website show up in fiddler?

Answer (score 3):

The thing was that IE had cache: true as standard, or at least I think it has as setting cache: false made the right data show. In IE it was always showing old data.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://domain.com/Service.svc/data", cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.d.test);
    }
});
```

Comment: The default for cache: in the $.ajax() call is always true unless the dataType is set to "jsonp" or "script". It's just that Firefox will still retrieve the fresh data anyway and IE won't.

Comment: okey, I use dataType: "json", what is the difference between json and jsonp?

Comment: JSONP is "JSON with padding" - it allows for callback function. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see what happens:

```
  jQuery.get("http://domain.com/Service.svc/data", 
  function(data) {
      alert(data.d.test);
  },"json");
```

Not sure if this helps though...

Answer (score 0):

Try including the following options on your .ajax() call:

```
data: "{}",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

There's a few ASP.Net and IE "gotchas" when consuming web services with jQuery. [Read here](http://encosia.com/2008/06/05/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "http://domain.com/Service.svc/data",
dataType: "json",
success: function(jsondata) {
    data=eval("("+jsondata+")");
    alert(data.d.test);
  }
});
```

or if you don't want to use eval then give header of content type "text/javascript" or you can do some thing like contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", as above told by Lance McNearney

Answer (score -1):

Try running the same script without the `dataType`, you should get the raw JSON string as `data`. Alert that out and you'll see if the data is passed in the right form.