# Getting JSON data with Ajax from PHP+Zend not working in IE only

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer

I have a problem when trying to get JSON data with Ajax and on Internet Explorer only.

I'm using this jQuery code :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "./ajaxglobal/chargementcommandes", 
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Success : "+data);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error : "+textStatus+" / "+errorThrown);
    }
});
```

With "chargementcommandes" being a PHP/Zend page.

The PHP code of "chargementcommandes", simplified for testing, is the following :

```
echo '[
        { "data" : "A node", "children" : [ { "data" : "Only child", "state" : "closed" } ], "state" : "open" },
        "Ajax node"
]';
```

Everything is working fine in Firefox and Chrome (I get the expected data), but in Internet Explorer (tested in IE8 and IE9), I get "Success : undefined" from the alert. So the Ajax call doesn't return anything. I tried many things but I didn't succeed to get rid of this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance !

EDIT : Added type, cache and contenttype in jQuery code. Still "Success : undefined" response...

Comment: With what `Content-Type` the server is responding?

Comment: I hope this solution could help you (it works for me) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037412/ajax-call-from-jquery-works-in-firefox-but-not-in-ie8

Comment: I've edited my Ajax code, to ensure that the content-type is ok and that no cache is used :

`$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "./ajaxglobal/chargementcommandes", 
 cache: false,
 dataType: "json",
 contentType: "application/json",
 success: function(data) {
  alert("Success : "+data);
 },
 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  alert("Error : "+textStatus+" / "+errorThrown);
 }
});`

I still have "Success : undefined".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the headers are correct, for the json response, as raina77ow suggested.

The correct header for json is "application/json", this header is set like this:

`header('Content-type: application/json');`